# authSubToken exception in Android

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I am using the following code to get Authsubtoken from my android application; following is the code:

```
 GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(myCtx,  "mymail@gmail.com","oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")
```

With this code, I get the following exception:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
```

How to overcome this exception?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html)

Comment: How to get "MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE" in the link you gave

Comment: It's just an integer variable, you can give any number that later you have to use with `onActivityResult()` see that example on that link

Comment: if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask();
           }
-- do I eed to set the result as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this exception

```
...
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
   startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
...
```

check out more here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14386248/760489

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142977/760489

Comment: How can I get "REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION" . If you check the first link you provided, I have already added a comment in the answer, stating the same.