# Google Drive implementation in android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

i am implementing Google Drive in Android with Java code i didnt use Android formats,

i just created client id and i used in Manifest

```html
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=344123456789"/>
```

and my code to create folder is

```html
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
service = getDriveService(credential);
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(path);
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

                    File fileMetadata = new File();
                    fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
                    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

                    File file = UploadPicture.service.files().create(fileMetadata)
                            .setFields("id")
                            .execute();
```

this is my code to create folder, but if i am using it from Activity it works but i am using fragments so i got UserRecoverableAuth exception please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Villonava, I think you are having trouble with Google Authentication Error when using your fragments. The [UserRecoverableAuth](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException#public-constructor-summary) exception means:

> UserRecoverableAuthExceptions signal Google authentication errors that
>   can be recovered with user action, such as a **user login**.

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015125/authsubtoken-exception-in-android?lq=1), the OP used try catch block:

```
...
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
   startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
...
```

Doing this will trigger an intent to authorize your activity/app. Also try following the [Drive quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) for Android, it is a step-by-step guide showing how to authorize and upload a file to Drive: