# Getting Google API access and avoiding UserRecoverableAuthIOException

Tags: android, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm using GMail API.
Currently, I ask for `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission and after that, I try to send some kind of a 'test' email.

If this is the user's first time, most likely `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` exception will be raised and I'll use its intent for asking his approval.

Is it possible to check this before trying to send and avoiding getting the exception?
Something like 'check_permission'?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this post regarding `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`: [Android Drive API: getting Sys.err UserRecoverableAuthIOException if i merge code to other projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142108/android-drive-api-getting-sys-err-userrecoverableauthioexception-if-i-merge-cod)

> You should catch the `UserRecoverableAuthException` and in the catch
>   block, you recover the `Intent` from the exception by calling
>   `UserRecoverableAuthException#getIntent()`. Start that intent to take
>   user to the `OAuth2` permission page for your app.
>
> Sample code -
>
> ```
> try {
>     Drive service = Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
>         .build();
>     // Do whatever you want with the Drive service
> } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
>     startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
> }
> ```

Comment: I know what to do with it once it's thrown. I want to know if the auth is given in order to avoid this from happening.